# Aitextgen doesn't generate any new text

Tags: python, large-language-model

So I'm using the aitextgen library to finetune gptneo. However once I did that and generated some text, it just spewed out the exact same sentences as in the text.

```
from aitextgen import aitextgen
ai = aitextgen(model="EleutherAI/gpt-neo-125M", to_gpu=True)
ai.train('speoof.txt',
         line_by_line=False,
         from_cache=False,
         num_steps=3000,
         generate_every=1000,
         save_every=1000,
         save_gdrive=False,
         learning_rate=1e-3,
         fp16=False,
         batch_size=1, 
         )
```

As requested here is some data
https://pastebin.com/zZyG77BD
Above is the code I use. How do I get it to generate somewhat original text?

Comment: Can you provide some data from speoof.txt so that we can test?

Comment: @rikyeah  I have uploaded some of the text data